# JSON Float In TradingView Alert

Tags: json, pine-script

I am constructing an automated stoploss mechanism to send pinescript JSON alerts to flask and then on to another application. The bot will set the stoploss level
I can get the full JSON message across, but I am having issues where I cant seem to insert a variable from a float into the JSON alert.
The error in pinescript is a bit confusing as it says expecting a float not a string. But in the PS script the variable is only 'ever' a float.
" Cannot call 'operator +' with 'expr1'=string. The argument should be of type: series[float]"
The next thing I tried what to convert the float into a string and then insert that in to the JSON script. That seems to have read the correct price level from the variable, but the issue is now the broker was expecting a float and not a string and rejects the order. So its a bit of a rock and a hard place.
I want to avoid having to convert the string back into a float on the receiving server if possible. (float-->string-->float)
I suspect my syntax is wrong or I need to use another method. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
var symbol = syminfo.tickerid
var trailPrice = 0.00
t_trailPrice = float(variation -spread)


var avPrefix = "e=alpacapaper  "  + " s=" + symbol 

//IBK Message
if (barstate.islast)
    if (t_trailPrice > trailPrice or trailPrice == 0.00) and barstate.isconfirmed 
        trailPrice := t_trailPrice
        alert('{"ticker": "' + syminfo.ticker + '", "strategy": {"order_action": "buy", "order_contracts": 144.66, "order_price": "' +  t_trailPrice + '"}}', freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 5 tostring() has been changed to the str. namespace. To change a float or int to string you can now use the str.tostring() function. eg.

```
+ str.tostring(t_trailPrice) + etc.
```

Cheers my friend

**EDIT**

I see you have an extra set of quotations that is likely causing your issue. Be mindful of the construction of your Dict. and send alerts to your email to verify how they are rendering. This code here renders the trailprice as a float.

```
//IBK Message
if (barstate.islast)
    if (t_trailPrice > trailPrice or trailPrice == 0.00) and barstate.isconfirmed 
        trailPrice := t_trailPrice
        alert('{"ticker": "' + syminfo.ticker + '", "strategy": {"order_action": "buy", "order_contracts": 144.66, "order_price": ' +  str.tostring(t_trailPrice) + '}}', freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Cheers and best of luck

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. To clarify I can convert the float to a string and it be sent in JSON already, but the receiving server expects the message as a float. In pine JSON alerts , I cant figure out how to send the JSON message as a float so the server will accept it. I suspect I will have to convert it back to a float on the server side.

Comment: I have edited the answer with an example of implementation. You had an extra set of quotes around trailPrice turning it to string